# Published Service Stack service returning a 404 error

Tags: servicestack

I've been recently trying out service stack for a future project and have been enjoying the framework. In Visual Studio, I have no issues getting the service to work however it returns a 404 error when trying to reach the resource after being published on IIS. It queries Mongo for the service, so maybe theirs some run time issue there. Anyone have issues after publication where the service didn't work?

Comment: I suggest you provide details of your IIS config, .NET config and any configuration you are doing for ServiceStack, and perhaps as well the part that queries Mongo.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was. It was a assembly version issue. I had to build all of my projects and then publish.